# Finding the numbers of functions $ f : \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} \to \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} $ such that $ |f[A]| = 2 $

Tags: combinatorics

Let $ A = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\} $. I want to find the number functions $ f : A \to A $ such that $ \left|f\left[A\right]\right| = 2$. Did I do it correctly?

Choose $ 2 $ random elements, $ i, j $ from $ A $ - there are $ \binom{5}2 = 10 \, $ ways to do so.

$ \forall x \in A, f\left(x\right) = i \lor f\left(x\right) = j $. Therefore, there are $ 10\cdot2^5 $ such functions. However, we need to subtract the cases where $ f\left[A\right] = \{i\} \lor f\left[A\right] = \{j\}, $ there are $ 5  $ such cases and therefore there are, overall, $ 315 $ functions that satisfy the requirement.

Comment: the first pass counts each constant function multiple times, not just twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite, but very close. For a given $i$ and $j$, you need to substract the cases where $ f\left[A\right] = \{i\} \lor f\left[A\right] = \{j\}$. There are $2$ such cases: either all elements map to $i$ or all map to $j$. (Thus, for a given $i$ and $j$, there are $2^5-2$ functions with $f\left[A\right] = \{i,j\}$.)

All in all, there are $10\cdot \left(2^5-2\right) = 300$ functions $f$ with this property.